# When click in one element, the other ones disable in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my problem

I have a simple array with names, and when I click in one element, this element will be active and the another one false

**The problem**

When i click in one element, all elements turn into active

**What I want**

When I click in "name 1" the background turn into red and the other ones the background turn into white, when I click in "name 2" the background turn into red and the others ones white, and so on

**Here is what I've been trying to do**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-saha-8ho1u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For having just one selected always, use the key:

```
  const handleSelect = key => {
    setSelect(key);
  };
```

And in the selection:

```js
        <Select
          key={key}
          // Passa status de ativo e inativo com true e false
          status={select === key}
          // Altera o status de select ao clicar
          click={() => handleSelect(key)}
          // Nome do usuário
          user={name}
        />
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

//
// COMPONENT FILHO
//

function Select({ user, click, status }) {
  return (
    <li className={status ? "active" : null} onClick={click}>
      {user}{" "}
    </li>
  );
}

const names = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"];

//
// COMPONENT PAI
//

export default function App() {
  const [select, setSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = key => {
    setSelect(key);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {names.map((name, key) => (
        <Select
          key={key}
          // Passa status de ativo e inativo com true e false
          status={select === key}
          // Altera o status de select ao clicar
          click={() => handleSelect(key)}
          // Nome do usuário
          user={name}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hopper-ozlqi

Preview:

[image: YiJaVb7.gif (174×162)]

---

**Problem**

You have a common `Select` variable that decides the state of everything. You need to have one per each select.

Move the following:

```js
  const [select, setSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setSelect(!select);
  };
```

Inside the component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

//
// COMPONENT FILHO
//

function Select({ user, click }) {

  const [select, setSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setSelect(!select);
  };

  return (
    <li className={select ? "active" : null} onClick={handleSelect}>
      {user}
    </li>
  );
}

const names = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"];

//
// COMPONENT PAI
//

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {names.map(name => (
        <Select
          user={name}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lumiere-1jdoh

This one is just identifying you the issue and it's going to have individual states.

Preview:

[image: 3OkNnbf.gif (154×154)]

Comment: @Henrique You're welcome! Glad I was able to help. Have a safe and nice day! 

Comment: Praveen Kumar, can I ask you something? what this line means? `status={select === key}` this line is kind of confusing to me, we are comparing the value true and false with a number?

Comment: @Henrique the `status` needs to be a boolean value. In this case, I am using `key` to identify the individual elements. Since we just need only one, and at a point of time, the `status` can hold only one value, it will have either true or false with that particular one.

Comment: Praveen Kumar, thank you again, now everything makes sense to me, it was an amazing solution :D